Websocket onerror event gives no information
I am developing a client and server application where a websocket will be used to maintain communications.  I create a websocket:
function DebugMsg(msg) {
    var msgdump = document.getElementById("msgdump");
    if (msgdump == null || typeof msgdump === "undefined") {
        return;
    }
    var strContent;    
    if (typeof msg == "string" && msg.length > 0) {
        strContent = msg;
    }
    if (typeof msg == "object" && typeof msg.message == "string") {
        strContent = msg.message;
    }
    if (typeof strContent == "string" && strContent.length > 0) {
        strContent = (new Date()).toUTCString() + ", " + strContent + "..."; 
        msgdump.innerHTML = strContent + "\r\n" + msgdump.innerHTML;
    }
}
function InstallServiceTimer(intInterval) {    
    if (intServiceInterval != intInterval) {
        tmrService = setInterval(ServiceRequests, intInterval);
        if (tmrService != null && typeof tmrService == "object") {       
            intServiceInterval = intInterval;
        }
    }
    if (!(tmrService == null || typeof tmrService === "undefined")) {
        DebugMsg("tmrService set-up, interval: " + intInterval + "ms");
    }
}
//Function called when service request timer expires, no arguments
function ServiceRequests() { 
    if (!(typeof webSocket == "object"
       && typeof webSocket.readyState == "number" 
              && webSocket.readyState == 1)) {
        return;
    }
    objServiceInfo[cstrServiceInfoTagRequests]++;
    var intServiceReqRespDiff = objServiceInfo[cstrServiceInfoTagRequests] 
                                - objServiceInfo[cstrServiceInfoTagResponses];
    if (intServiceReqRespDiff > cintServiceNoResponses
        && intServiceInterval != cintServiceRequestAltInterval) {
    //Stop the existing timer
        clearInterval(tmrService);
    //Reset request and response counters
        objServiceInfo[cstrServiceInfoTagRequests] = 
        objServiceInfo[cstrServiceInfoTagResponses] = 0;
    //Create a new timer with the slower interval
        InstallServiceTimer(cintServiceRequestAltInterval);
        return;
    }
    DebugMsg("Sending: \"" + cstrSendMsg + "\", to: " + cstrServerSocketIP);
    webSocket.send(cstrSendMsg);
}
function CreateWebSocket() {
    try {
    //Set-up timer to monitor webSocket object
        if (typeof tmrWebSocketMonitor == "undefined") {
            tmrWebSocketMonitor = setInterval(function() {
                if (webSocket == null ) {
    //Do nothing webSocket hasn't been created yet
                    return;
                }
                if (!(typeof webSocket == "object"
                   && typeof webSocket.readyState == "number" 
                          && webSocket.readyState == 1)) {
                    webSocket.close();
                }
            }, 5000);
        }
        webSocket = new WebSocket(cstrServerSocketIP);    
        webSocket.onclose = (event) => {
            var strReason = "";    
            if (typeof event == "object") {
                if (typeof event.code == "number") {
                    strReason += "code[" + event.code + "]";
                    var strError = cobjWebSocketErrors[event.code];
                    if (typeof strError == "string") {
                        strReason += ":" + strError;
                    }
                }
                if (typeof event.reason == "string" && event.reason.length > 0) {
                    if (strReason.length > 0) {
                        strReason += ", ";    
                    }
                    strReason += "reason:\"" + event.reason + "\"";
                }
            }
            DebugMsg("webSocket.onclose " + strReason);    
        };    
        webSocket.onerror = (event) => {
            DebugMsg("webSocket.onerror" 
                + ((typeof event == "object"
                && typeof event.data == "string") ? ":" + event.data : ""));
        };
        webSocket.onmessage = (event) => { 
            DebugMsg("webSocket.onmessage"
                + ((typeof event == "object"
                    && typeof event.data == "string") ? ":" + event.data : ""));
        };
        webSocket.onopen = () => {
            DebugMsg("webSocket.onopen");
        };
        //Set-up timer to send requests for data updates
        InstallServiceTimer(cintServiceRequestInterval);
    } catch (e) {
        DebugMsg(e);
    }
}

I'm using Chrome as the browser and the Developer Tools within Chrome to help debug.  I can see when the onerror event occurs and there is nothing useful in the passed event that I can see that suggests what the error is, no code, no message.  Can anyone shed any light on how I can track what the cause of this is?

The onerror event in WebSocket is a simple event and does not provide detailed error information. To identify the error, you can use the onclose event and analyze the code returned within the onclose event

Yes, I see with the onclose there is a code 1006 which represents Abnormal Closure, but there is no stack trace or clue given to why or where, whats the point of the error event if it provides no information?
